# Snowflake scripting - store number variable in sql statement resulting in count

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a sql statement in a stored proc that I can't run without first building a string dynamically by passing in several variables. Then I run execute immediate :sqlString and I'm trying to return the resultset into an integer as the sql statement is a count. Is this possible? Or how do I return a count from a SQL statement that I can't use table literals to build the sql statement.

```
create or replace procedure(v_comp_key varchar,v_dest_table varchar, v_stg_table varchar)

returns integer

language sql

as

declare
  count_records_data_change integer := 0;

  str_records_no_change varchar;
 
begin

select count(*) into :count_records_data_change from(select :v_comp_key from table(:v_dest_table) where current_flag = true intersect select :v_comp_key from table(:v_stg_table));


str_records_no_change :=
'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT ' ||  :v_comp_key
      || ' FROM ' || :v_dest_table || ' A WHERE A.CURRENT_FLAG = TRUE INTERSECT SELECT '
      || :v_comp_key || ' FROM ' || :v_stg_table || ' B)';
     count_records_data_change :=  (execute immediate str_records_no_change)
return count_records_data_change;

end;
```

Comment: Is this using SQL Scripting?  If so you need to use a resultset/cursor to process the result from a query. The Snowflake Scripting documentation has lots of examples

Comment: Can you share your code and the call statement for the SP?

Comment: Here is the piece I am trying to do.  I tried using table literals but I dont think I can pass the columns to select as a variable. So I can build a string but dont know how to pass the return value from the execute into  an integer.  Also I know how to use resultset/cursor but I want to store in an integer so I can sum on the returned count.  I added the sql in the original post.

Comment: It's a little circuitous, but in your sp you could create a temporary table, write your dynamic query to store the result there, and then use a statically defined query to pull that integer result from the temp table and return that value in from the sp. Not the most elegant, but it will work.

Comment: @JimDemitriou I'm open to doing this but I'm not going to create a temp table to only store a count record so I can return it.  The other idea is with my other queries since I'm doing DML statements I use Selete $1 into :count from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));  But I believe this only will return the count based on what was executed by DML.  A select statement this wont apply

Comment: I got it working this way! I was able to do this by executing the select statement and then I use Select $1 into :count from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));  this would return the result count from the query into a variable

Comment: You can dynamically construct the SQL statement, assign it to a resultset and then read through the result using a cursor. This is covered here with examples: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/resultsets.html#declaring-a-resultset